# Making Horizontal UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am trying to make a Horizontal UIPickerView. But i have som issues with the width. As you can se in the top of the image above[image]

I want the width of the PickerView to be = view.frame.size.width, but for some reason it keeps very small. In my code i have:

```
let cityPicker = UIPickerView()
var rotationAngle: CGFloat!
let width:CGFloat = 100
let height:CGFloat = 100

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
cityPicker.delegate = self
        cityPicker.dataSource = self
        cityPicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
        self.view.addSubview(cityPicker)
        rotationAngle = -90 * (.pi/180)
        cityPicker.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)

        }

  func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return byer.count
    } 

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont (name: "Baskerville-Bold", size: 30)
        label.text = byer[row]
        view.addSubview(label)

        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi/180))
        return view
    }
```

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should just use autolayout, but if you want manual layout you cannot use your view's frame in `viewDidLoad`.  At that point the frame will equal what is in the storyboard or nib file, and will not reflect the actual device or view hierarchy.  You should put your manual sizing logic in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  When this function is called your view has the correct size and you can use it to set your subviews.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what @Josh Homann meant by "just use autolayout", but I had to create a rotated picker

```
private let horizontalPickerView: UIPickerView = {
    let view = UIPickerView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.showsSelectionIndicator = false
    view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -90 * (.pi / 180))
    return view
}()
```

then set its constraints to empirically calculated

```
horizontalPickerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth),
horizontalPickerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
horizontalPickerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
horizontalPickerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainButton.topAnchor, constant: -32)
```

and also set items width (actually height) in UIPickerViewDelegate method

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    100
}
```

to get this

[image]

Comment: how to turn it flat?

Comment: via UIScrollView probably

Answer (score 0):

```
var rotationAngle : CGFloat!
```

> In your ViewDidLoad

```
rotationAngle = -90 * (.pi / 180 )
```

> write this function in your class

```
   func rotatePickerView(pickerView : UIPickerView) {
    let y = pickerView.frame.origin.y
    let x = pickerView.frame.origin.x

    pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)
    pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: pickerView.frame.height , height: pickerView.frame.width)
}
```

> Also we need to rotate the label as we are rotating our pickerview, Now in your viewForRow method. (These are Pickerview delegate methods.)

```
let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40, weight: .bold)
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi / 180 ))

    //Put your values in an array like Minutes,Temperature etc.
    label.text = minutes[row]

    return label
```

> Call the rotatePickerView function in your viewDidLoad and put your pickerview as a parameter input, Done, Thank you ;)